# Этимология слова "нищий"

Tags: этимология

Интересно, а каково происхождение слова "нищий"? Мне почему-то кажется, что оно родственно слову "снискать", но я точно не уверена. И, если так, то получается: нищий — тот, кто снискал какую-то помощь?

Comment: Абсолютно точным и правильным в польском языке переводом русского слова "нищенство" будет :- "dziadostwo", которое не является однокоренным русскому "нищета" -на польском "ubóstwo" или реже "nędza" фонетчск звчние блзко к [нендза]. Эти слова лишь отдаленно сродни (созвучны) русскому "нужда" или "убожество", хоть и являються точным словарным переводом к "нищета" (однокоренное к рассматриваемому в заданном вопросе). Польское "dziad", на сегодняшний день при переводе на Русский (после основного значения) в подробном словаре, ♦ пометить надлежит как отдаленно близкое по смыслу к Русскому устаревше

Comment: 1. *являюсь носителем Польского языка* *являюсь носителем Польского языка*  - зачем заглавные?

Comment: 2. *готов дискутировать с желающими* - о чем? О польском языке? Это не по теме ресурса. Да и вообще дискуссии тут - не формат. Вы на исходный вопрос ответить не хотите?

Comment: ИзвиняюсьЕщеРаз,за мою"Русскую грамматику",но реально заинтрсвшсь..Всеж нахожуНекую связ с польскими словами (напр., со словом "znikomy"[зНiкомый] и некоторыми другими...Обяснить более подробно чел-ку незнакомому с польским, именно эту СВЯЗЬ довольно проблематично..но онаВсеж просматртвается...НуВотНапр еще польское "niczpoń"естьКэтомуВопросу,обяснятДолго...пытаюсОбьяснитьВсветеСлавянскоИстории...собраВсеВоЕдиноИсообразуяСответамиДругихПриидемКистинеОименноЗаданномВопросе  с "ниц", "нищ", "низ" и т.п. УважаюДажеЛюбРусс-яз.Упольского филологаНесколькоИначеВзглядТолькоИвсего.ПожалустаНеУдаляйте.

Comment: Послушайте, это ресурс РУССКОГО языка. Никто не будет против, если вы используете какие-то соответствия с польским (и вообще любыми другими) в ответе на поставленный вопрос. Но вы-то даже не попытались сформулировать ответ на исходный вопрос.

Comment: Если вы хотите обсудить что-то вне этой темы - так задайте отдельный вопрос. Но только по русскому языку, а не по польскому.

Comment: А разве я задаю здесь вопросы? Вношу факты,это да!

Comment: *.Обяснить более подробно... чел-ку незнакомому с польским* - я немного знаком с польским. Во всяком случае - письменный текст немного понимаю. Но зачем объяснять то, о чем никто вовсе и не спрашивал? Неблагодарный это труд, есть куда более приличествующие ситуации занятия.

Comment: *А разве я задаю здесь вопросы?* - вот именно. А на ресурсе это именно задают вопросы - и отвечают на них.  *Вношу факты,это да!* - а вот "факты", не имеющие отношения к теме - это, скорее,  флуд. Если не троллинг. По моему скромному мнению.

Comment: Так ведь не стану же я здесь отвечать (относительно нищ,ниц,..) на польском. Всего лишь дополняю сведениями (способствую ответам). Уверен многим это только рассширит обзор знаний касаемо вопроса Fuchoin'а Kazuki где речь идет о  славянском происхождении корня, (в письменных памятниках, фонетическом созвучии и т.п.) Писал бы в комментах к другим ответам но неимею достаточно прав на это (пока)

Comment: Свои вопросы я задаю под соответствующую гиперссылку, и они есть там,...

Comment: *Так ведь не стану же я здесь отвечать* - Так и я об этом. Не хотите отвечать - хотя бы не флудите. Моя рекомендация - **сообщение ваше удалить, как не содержащее ответа на вопрос.** Дискуссию на этом считаю закрытой. Вы не настолько новый участник, чтобы объяснять вам правила ресурса.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133280/discussion-between-behemothus-and-henna-gaijin-user199525).

Comment: Henna Gaijin
Ведь нет вааще в языке даже в староСВЕТском(польск.,адаптрвано фонетч.)по русски назовем  "былинном" польском слова "niszczotny" употребленное для сравнения учасником СОАН выше в одном из комментов...диалектов польских, наперечёт не так уж и много в сравнении с Россией...У меня недостаточно возможностей как у новичка,чтоб я мог ответиль СОАНу в комменте...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этимологию слова НИЩИЙ Семенов А.В. объясняет так:
"Древнерусское – нишь.
Старославянское – ништь.
Общеславянское – niscь.

Прилагательное «нищий», означающее «очень бедный», «живущий на подаяния», *заимствовано из старославянского языка в XI в.*

Родственными являются:
Украинское – нищий.
Польское – niszczotny.
Производные: нищ, нищета, нищенство, нищать".

Answer (score 3):

Этимология слова "нищий" до сих пор не разгадана. Во всяком случае, всё, что опубликовано, не оставляет уверенности, что это верно. Мне посчастливилось понять это слово - можете считать это озарением, и я делюсь с Вами. 
Предки русских вышли из Индии. Об этом свидетельствуют многочисленные совпадения в русском и санскрите. В Индии они оставили после себя кастовое общество, поэтому есть все основания полагать, что именно в таком обществе долгое время существовали протославяне. Общество было расслоено, кто-то находился на самом верху и относился к категории "высший". На противоположном полюсе - в самом низу, находились те, кого именовали "низшими".
 Ещё совсем недавно слово "низ" в русском языке звучало, как "ниц" (падать ниц). Значит, "низший" произносилось, как "ницший". Сочетание "цш" = "щ". Так появилось слово "нищий" - человек, находящийся в самом низу, на самом дне общества. 
Это очень древнее слово, и его смысловое наполнение никак не связано с количеством личного имущества, но определяет социальный статус. 
С уважением, Богорадо Сергей Спартакович, E-mail: bogorado@mail.ru

Comment: Очень интересно! Напрашивается мысль, что Ницше был из этих самых, низших))) Кстати, зачем нашим предкам было "выходить" из Индии? Может, кто-то туда и зашел, но вот вышли одни цыгане и до сих пор бродят, назад дороги не найдут.

Comment: >Церковный словарь 1815 : "Нишшїй -
уравнителн. степень отъ имени низкїй". 
>В САР читаем : "Высокій... вышшій,
уравн. степень". 

Пришлось заглянуть в "Грамматику ЦСЯ" Алипия Гамановича и прочесть пояснение : "Полные окончания прилагательных **сравнительной степени** суть следующие : а) У прилагательных с суфф. *ьш* : -(ь)ш-їй, -(ь)ш-ая, -(ь)ш-ее. **Выш-шїй, выш-шая, выш-шее.**" Как я и предположил ранее, *уравнительная степень* = сравнительная степень. Никаких противоречий нет)))

Answer (score 3):

Это не ответ, поскольку мои комментарии методично удаляются другими пользователями, вынужден писать тут. 
Ну что ж, придется повторить.

Сравнительной степени в современном понимании в ЦСЯ нет и не было.
Термин "Уравнительная" встречается у Ломоносова - тоже не совсем в современном понимании - и применительно к русскому языку.
Главное то, что в ЦСЯ не было самостоятельных формы для сравнительной и превосходной степени, обычно говорилось, что для превосходной используется сравнительная, хотя реально дело обстояло наоборот: в выражениях типа "Я перешел на высший уровень" прилагательное могло означать и "более высокий" и "самый высокий".

ЗЫ

> > Любой желающий в состоянии прочесть "Грамматику ЦСЯ" А.Гамановича) По этой ссылке можно найти и ознакомиться самостоятельно, без навязчивых суфлеров.
> > (C) grumant

Надеюсь именно это и обнаружил grumant в учебнике Гамановича "без навязчивых суфлеров". 
Для остальных могу рекомендовать ссылки для прямого скачивания 
http://ksana-k.narod.ru/menu/csl.html
Из популярных учебников ЦСЯ нет только Ёлкиной и Хабургаева.
Могу, кстати, и их выложить.

> > я поддерживаю точку зрения Черных, который предложил корень nizь в качестве источника слова нищий. Очень хорошая версия.

Вы так часто трёте посты вместе с точками зрения, что немудрено забыть. Очень хорошая манера, кстати. Вопрос в другом, с Вами кто-то спорил по сути этого высказывания?
Мне не понравились два момента, совершенно другого плана. 
Первое: однозначная трактовка "уравнительный" как "сравнительный" со ссылкой на Ломоносова, который этим вопросом (тем более - применительно к ЦСЯ) не занимался.
И второй - бездоказательное отнесение к одному индоевропейскому корню вопреки другому (Фасмеру), хотя тут я даже не встревал особо, ибо не знаю наверняка, а объективно -  недоказуемо.

Кстати, Гаманович - не "А.", а Николай Михайлович.
Отец Алипий - его монашеское имя.
Так что либо "Н. Гаманович", либо "о. Алипий", либо уж "арх. Алипий."

Это так, к вопросу о суфлерах.

> > Девичью фамилию матери отца Алипия на всякий случай озвучьте, а то я совсем растерямшись от вашей эрудиции. А памяти хватит все скопировать, дабы никто отпереться не смог? Тады копируйте, бытописатель вы наш))) (просительно) А можно говорить - протоиерей Сергий Булгаков? А можно - прот. С.Булгаков?? Ой, а можно... (в 
> > ужасе замолкает)

(grumant)

Про мать Гамановича ничего сказать не могу. Не знаю. Возможно, есть в википедии. Да, есть: Людмила Гаманович (урождённая Мартынова) http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B9_%28%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%29 А зачем оно Вам, можно поинтересоваться?

Про Булгакова - не понимаю вопроса. Он - Сергей Николаевич, по рождению. Постриг не принимал.
Все остальное - см. мне в профиль.

Comment: Любой желающий может прочесть "Грамматику ЦСЯ" А.Гамановича) По этой [ссылке](http://ekislova.ru/russian/gram) можно найти и ознакомиться самостоятельно, без навязчивых суфлеров.

Comment: Девичью фамилию матери отца Алипия на всякий случай озвучьте, а то я совсем растерямшись от вашей эрудиции. А памяти хватит все скопировать, дабы никто отпереться не смог? Тады копируйте, бытописатель вы наш))) (просительно) А можно говорить - протоиерей Сергий Булгаков? А можно - прот. С.Булгаков?? Ой, а можно... (в ужасе замолкает)

Comment: Как - не знаете?!! Вы позорите свой гордый профиль...

Answer (score 2):

> Происходит от праслав. формы
> *nīsti̯o-, от которой в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. нищь, ст.-слав.
> ништь (др.-греч. πένης, πτωχός),
> русск. нищий, укр. ни́щий, сербохорв.
> ни̏шт «бедный», польск. niszczotny —
> то же. Праслав.* nīsti̯o- родственно
> др.-инд. níṣṭyas «чужой, нездешний»,
> niḥ «наружу». Использованы данные
> словаря М. Фасмера

Нет никаких причин считать *"нищий"* и *"снискать"* родственными. Они даже не созвучны.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, "нищий" - от слов "ни с чем" (ср. польск. "жебрак": "же" - который, "брак" - нет (не имеет), то есть "который не имеет")

Answer (score 1):

По всей видимости, польский "жебрак" аналогичен русскому слову "неимущий". Слова "нищий" и "неимущий" на сегодняшний день практически слились в своём значении. В древности же, когда какого-либо имущества вообще было мало, а котлы для варки пищи передавались из поколения в поколение по наследству, статус человека определялся прежде всего происхождением. Например, у воина зачастую ничего не было, кроме одежды, но воина никогда не называли нищим.

Answer (score 0):

В славянских языках (кроме украинского) нет схожих по звучанию слов со значением "нищий". Даже в украинском языке слово "нищий" в этом значении малоупотребимо. Используется другое слово - жебрак. Сравним с другими славянскими языками: белорус. - жабрак, польск. - żebrak, болг. - просяк, босн. - prosjak, македон. - просјак, серб. - просјак, словен. - berač, словац. - žobrák, чеш. - žebrák, хорват. - prosjak. Почему же только в русском нищий? Загадка. Искать корни в Индии среди неприкасаемых, конечно, интересно, но, может быть, проще посмотреть на родственные языки. Что по сути означает нищий?
Википедия: Нищие - категория людей, находящихся за крайней чертой бедности, вынужденных жить за счёт подаяний и благотворительности со стороны родственников, благотворительных организаций или государства.

Викисловарь: нищий

1. такой, у которого не хватает денежных или иных средств для поддержания нормальных условий жизни, крайне бедный, неимущий; 2. тот, кто живёт подаянием, побирается. 3. перен. скудный, недостаточный

Синонимы

1. Неимущий, бедный, бедствующий, нуждающийся, малоимущий, небогатый, малообеспеченный, необеспеченный
2. побирушка, попрошайка, паупер
3. скудный, недостаточный, бедный

В словаре Ожегова: НИЩИЙ, -ая, -ее. 1. Очень бедный, неимущий. 2. Человек, живущий подаянием, собирающий милостыню.
В словаре Ефремовой: Нищий. 1. Тот, кто живет подаянием. 2. Бедный, неимущий человек.

Теперь зададимся вопросом - откуда берутся нищие, обездоленные, неимущие, вынужденные попрошайничать люди. Нищие - следствие разрухи, следствие войн, разрушений, принесенных войнами. Нищие - от уничтожения, которое приносит война и подобные ей конфликты. У-нич-тожения. Знаете, как по-украински будет "уничтожать"? Знищувати или Нищити. Приведу значения слова "нищити" - 1. Убиваючи, отруюючи, топчучи, ламаючи і т. ін., позбавляти життя, припиняти існування кого-, чого-небудь. 2. Виснажувати, фізично ослаблювати (організм, тіло). 3. Руйнувати, палити, ламати. 4. Грабувати, розоряти. 5. Позбавляти когось чого-небудь.
Теперь сравним слово "уничтожать" - украинское "нищити" - с аналогичными по значению словами в других славянских языках, и посмотрим, имеется ли между ними связь. По-хорватски уничтожать будет uništiti. По-болгарски - унищожи, по-боснийски - uništiti, по-сербски - уништити, по-македонски - уништи, по-словенски - uničiti, на словацком и чешском - zničiť и zničit, на белорусском - знішчаць, по-польски - zniszczyć. По всему выходит, что нищета - это следствие у-нич-тожения, следствие разрушений, разрухи.
Выходит, слово "ничтожный" (очень малый, незначительный по количеству) и "нищий" (бедный, неимущий) однокоренные слова. У слова "ничто", кстати сказать, во всех славянских языках прослеживается всё тот же один родственный корень - нич, нищ и ниц.

Answer (score 0):

В той же википедии есть отсыл к древнеиндийскому níṣṭyas «чужой, нездешний», niḥ «наружу». Те же попрошайки из других краев (в стиле "сами мы не местные"), которые не собираются оставаться или же попробовали осесть рядом с имеющимся поселением. Были же мытари/просаки/жебраки ходившие с сумой/калитой и прочее. Опять-таки переселенцы без пожитков, чтобы ни было причиной миграции. Строили шалаши/землянки на границе поселений (снаружи кона) не имея возможности построить что-то основательное или же недопущенные в центральную часть поселения. Во многих городах до сих пор окраины одна большая трущоба.
Как вариант. На достоверность не претендую.

Answer (score 0):

Нищий - нисчий - ни с чем, т.е. у человека нет ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Довольно часто употребляемое в польском языке слово "znikomy" переводится как "мизерный" (хотя кроме него и есть польское "wymizerńiały" и подобное к неславянскому "мизер") и, вероятно, все ж, имеет что-то общее с "ниц" и "низ", обсуждаемыми здесь.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибается пользователь СОАН,(уж непомню возможно ВАЛЕНТИН) ибо совсем нет в польском язке слова "niszczotny"и небыло в древних языка вариациях,как и теперешних польских диалектах. Маленькая страна, не в пример России,и диалектов то всего несколько что широко извесны в среде филологов.Так же пользователь КОЛЕСО об общем корне "нищ" для всех славянских яз., слегка ошибается (напр., польско-украинское zniszczy [знiщы], для польши уж столетиями-давно"устарело" и признано пришедшим с Украины[!Востока Европы! Не отсюда ли корни Индо ?] и Русское "уничтож~ение" чаще повсемесно переводиться как unicestwi~ć [унiцэствi~eнie],чтобы дистанцироватьса от Украинизма (!холопы!) слова "(z)niszczyć". Хоть в "Советских" словарях и есть такой "унизительный" для польско-индивидуального патриотизма перевод.Как носитель Польского (по одному из родителей,поэтому извиняюсь за ошибки в моем Русском, который люблю)здесь подчеркну следующее:-
Абсолютно точным и правильным в польском языке переводом русского слова "нищенство" будет :- "dziadostwo", и несовсем "нищий" равно украинско-польскому [жебрак] которое не является однокоренным русскому "нищета" -на польском "ubóstwo" или реже "nędza" фонетичск звчние блзко к [нендза]. Эти слова лишь отдаленно сродни (созвучны) русскому "нужда" или "убожество", хоть и являються точным словарным переводом к "нищета" (однокоренное к рассматриваемому в заданном вопросе). Польское "dziad", на сегодняшний день при переводе на Русский (после основного значения) в подробном словаре,выделять(ромбиком)♦и пометить надлежит как отдаленно близкое по смыслу к Русскому былинно-устаревшему "убогий". Опять же, это не всмысле "калика перехожий" и даже не "юродивый". А точным переводом (не токмо в польском) слова "źebrak" [жебрак] на Русский является "попрошайка", что тоже, не однокоренное к "нищ" или "ниц" как и к "низ" обсуждаемым здесь нами. Так же у второго по-частоте употребления синонима к (не токмо) польскому "жебрак" слову "proszak" (переводится на Русс-яз., "просящий" но ни вкоем случае не как "проситель" в литературном "присутственном месте"напр., у Гоголя!)нет общего корня или основы с рассматриваемым здесь нами "нищ". Исходя из вышеизложенного ВСЕМИ кто принял участие в ответе на вопрос, можна резюмировать, что врядли есть какое либо общее происхождение в славянском мире, у слова "нищий" и глагольного "снискать",и происхождение корней: "нищ" /"ниц"/вероятно и "низ" следует искать в индо-санскритском ит.п. происхождении языка